# insert MSSQL more than 8000 characters in a nvarchar(max) field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, insert

While using sql 2005, it appears I am unable to insert more than 8000 characters in a nvarchar(max) field.

This is really puzzling. I have tried insert, update and update .write  with no luck.  I can't insert it completely in the console and in .net the error I consistently get is

> The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

The insert statement is

```
insert into tablename (columnname) values (' long text');
```

Update:

```
update tablename set columnname='long text'
```

Everything is always truncated at 8000 characters (the text is 11,000 characters). Running a few tests, I see that

```
select @@textsize
```

gives 2147483647

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: So where does the `data types text` bit come from? Are you having a `text` field after all?

Comment: Is it getting truncated, or are you getting an error? It's not clear from your questiont text.

Comment: when i insert from  the console it is getting truncated.

Comment: I should have clarified that i tried doing this both with ntext and nvarchar(max).  But all of this is with just nvarchar(max) the field used to be text. I dont know why it thinks it still is.

Comment: Checkout this post [on converting between NTEXT and NVARCHAR(MAX)](http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx) I wonder if you might be having a similar issue.

Comment: The message comes from SQL Server so you *have not* posted correct code or datatypes: you have text not a (max) type and you have + operator in SQL. This is not shown in the question. And your .net code that fails too? -1 for incomplete and poor question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code truncates the value somewhere. You did not include the entire code, so we cannot guess *where* it truncates. The usual place is parameter declarations. The correct code should be like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
     @"insert into table (column) values (@param)", conn, trn);
cmd.Paramaters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
cmd.Parameters["@param"].Value = myLongVariable;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new 
    SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) 
{ 
      con.Open(); 
      using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
      {
           string expression = "long text................................."; 
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
           cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure"; 
           cmd.Parameters.Add("Your long text Parameter Name ", 
                                SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = expression;    
           cmd.Connection = con; 
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this issue and eventually tracked it down to the ADO constant I was using in the VBA code that calls the stored procedure. Originally I was adVarChar which gave me the "String data, right truncation" message, but when I swapped this out for adLongVarChar it now works fine

Answer (score 0):

cmd.Paramaters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value=parametervaluehere;

where -1 means max length for varchar/nvarchar datatype.